# TimeSpan not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, timespan

Heres the code I have re arranged, but still have same problem, not able to find my start and end times on last page? How do I do this?

```
public void start()
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start();
        Response.Redirect("~/end.aspx");
    }
```

---

```
public void end()
    {
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    protected void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        end();
        Response.Redirect("~/display.aspx");
    }
```

---

```
public partial class display : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpent = endTime - startTime;

        lblDisplay.Text = string.Format("Time: {0}", timeSpent);
    }
}
```

---

Now can anyone help me on this?

Comment: _How do I take the times away and then display on the last page?_ What is that mean? Your question seems unclear to me. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: Why are you using these `Convert`s instead of just taking the `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: What substract? You define start and end and the timespent is simply not defined. Try reading a book about C# maybe? Basic syntax? Some basic logic helps too.

Comment: Btw, when the time is recorded/saved it will be saved on the first page when the user clicks a button, then on the last page when the user clicks the button, and then displayed on another page

Comment: using subtraction on two datetimes will give you a timespan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to convert this to a string.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
```

(Note: Those two times above will be identical)

Once you have done that, you can use one of the other techniques shown above to get the timespan:

```
var timeSpent = (end - start);
```

or

```
TimeSpan timeSpent = end.Subtract(start);
```

To display it:

```
Console.WriteLine(timeSpent.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Now, go code! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
//........    some code here.......
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan timeSpent = end - start;
```

and then use

```
timeSpent.TotalMilliseconds or timeSpent.TotalSeconds .....
```

the properties of the timespan are all in the intellisense (minutes/days/hours/seconds/milliseconds....)

Comment: No need for the brackets here - just `TimeSpan timeSpent = end - start;` is fine. You should also probably use `TotalMilliseconds` and `TotalSeconds` etc... the other properties aren't useful as often.

Comment: yes, I know, it is just an habit; for the Total prefix I've edited now, thanks

Comment: Then it's a habit to get out of, IMO. There's no benefit here at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
TimeSpan timeSpent = end.Subtract(start);
```

Comment: Or even use the `-` operator :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 TimeSpan span = end.Subtract ( start );
```

This will get you the time that elapased between the start and the end

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know working time, you could use Stopwatch class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx